# Using any and all (euler # 7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to find the 10,001st prime. This is what I had:

```
def seven(count):

    desired_count = count
    actual_count = 6
    number = 15

    while desired_count > actual_count:

        factors_in_number = range(int((number**.5)+1))
        _factors_in_number = factors_in_number[2:]

        print "prime count:"
        print actual_count
        print "current number:"
        print number
        print "factors:"
        print _factors_in_number

        if number % any(_factors_in_number) == 0:
            number += 2
            break

        elif number % all(_factors_in_number) != 0:
            actual_count += 1
            number += 2

    return number
```

I'm trying to short circuit the search through the list of factors with "any" and I was trying an else, but then did elif. Idk. 
Here's what I get:

```
seven(10001)
prime count:
6
current number:
15
factors:
[2, 3]
prime count:
6
current number:
17
factors:
[2, 3, 4]
prime count:
6
current number:
19
factors:
[2, 3, 4]
prime count:
6
current number:
21
factors:
[2, 3, 4]
prime count:
6
current number:
23
factors:
[2, 3, 4]
prime count:
6
current number:
25
factors:
[2, 3, 4, 5]
prime count:
6
current number:
27
factors:
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So, the list factors increase correctly, the number increases, but the prime counts don't, and it has something to do with the any's and all's. So how am I using the any and all wrong?

I know there are definitely faster ways, but I'm trying to just get my monster off of the ground. Thanks! Cheers

Comment: you want "if any(condition(x) for x in stuff" e.g. any(number % f for f in factors) for example. any() and all() return bools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not get the `actual_count` because your `any` and `all` were not used as intended. In fact, the  following `elif` block is never executed:

```
elif number % all(_factors_in_number) != 0:
     actual_count += 1
     number += 2
```

Because  `all(_factors_in_number)` is always `True` when applied in this way and *any_number mod True* is always Zero, since `True` is coerced as 1. So the condition is never passed. The `any` block instead is always  passed as long your *container* is *non-empty*.

---

You probably intend to have the check performed as:

```
elif all(number % some_integer!=0 for number in _factors_in_number):
     actual_count += 1
     number += 2
```

which ensures that the `mod` operation is performed on all members of the container and `all` enforces that the condition is passed for all the members. The same update should be applied to `any`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `all(_factors_in_number)` or `any(_factors_in_number)` is definitely not giving the result you are thinking it is:

```
>>> any([1,2,3,4])
True
>>> 7 % any([1,2,3,4]) #True is treated like 1
0
```

Prehaps take a look at `help(any)` to see how it actually works:

```
>>> help(any)
Help on built-in function any in module builtins:

any(iterable, /)
    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

    If the iterable is empty, return False.
```

So to correctly use the function the conditional needs to be in a loop inside the call, something like this:

```
if any(number%i == 0 for i in _factors_in_num):
#and then
if all(number%i != 0 for i in _factors_in_num):
```